# How to restore android phone system folders

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, restore, huawei-ascend-ii

I have deleted my rooted android phones system folders from pc and when I turned off phone, than turned on it doesn't turning on. how can I install new ROM when it is turned of. it is only showing phone brand logo (Huawei G700)

Comment: Start with our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) plus [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). And next time, before using "root powers", better make sure you know what you're doing – and be prepared for eventual results ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to boot into the bootloader, and if not already done flash a custom recovery (ClockworkMod or TWRP). After that boot into recovery from the bootloader. In your custom recovery, you should have the option to flash a package. Use your favorite custom ROM or your stock ROM as flash package and flash it. If it succeeds and you haven't deleted your data partition, you should be able to boot into your ROM without loosing any data (apps, settings accounts, etc.)